# Sim card USSD code running.. after a long stay not try again I said to myself

Tags: p-lang

my phone on time to daily packaged code running..
so after a long time
not try again
He refused to work for me like that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX5Vh.jpg) [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGbsr.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq6RV.jpg)
My phone samsung a90
how can i fix this please help me